# Python Linked list with Nodes: find minimum

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to create a find_min() method of my UnorderedList: class that is supposed to find the minimum number in the list.

```
def find_min(self):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.getData == None:
            found = True
            minimum = "None"
        else: 
    #this is where i got stuck....
```

The method is supposed to return "None" if the list is empty. I was trying to use Previous and Current to transverse through the nodes and compare them to each other to see what the minimum is but it failed.

Also I made a clear/delete_all method that is not working properly. It is supposed to clear all items from the list and leave an empty list.

```
def clear(self):
    current = self.head
    current.setNext(None)
    endOfList = current.getData()
    self.remove(endOfList)
```

Here's the rest of my two classes.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,initdata):
    self.data = initdata
    self.next = None

def getData(self):
    return self.data

def getNext(self):
    return self.next

def setData(self,newdata):
    self.data = newdata

def setNext(self,newnext):
    self.next = newnext

class UnorderedList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.count = 0

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.head == None

def add(self,item):
    temp = Node(item)
    temp.setNext(self.head)
    self.head = temp

def size(self):
    current = self.head
    count = 0
    while current != None:
        count = count + 1
        current = current.getNext()
    return count

def search(self,item):
    current = self.head
    found = False
    while current != None and not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            current = current.getNext()
    return found

def remove(self,item):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()

    if previous == None:
        self.head = current.getNext()
    else:
        previous.setNext(current.getNext())

def __str__(self):
    result = '['
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        result += str(current.getData()) + ', '
        current = current.getNext()
    result += ']'
    return result

def append(self, item):
    current = self.head
    while current.getNext() != None:
        current = current.getNext()
    current.setNext(Node(item))

def pop(self):
    current = self.head
    found = False
    endOfList = None
    while current != None and not found:
        if current.getNext() == None:
            found = True
            endOfList = current.getData()
            self.remove(endOfList)
        else:
            current = current.getNext()

def clear(self):
    current = self.head
    current.setNext(None)
    endOfList = current.getData()
    self.remove(endOfList)
```

Any help would be awesome thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what the problem is with your current code? How does your expected output differ from your actual output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding the minimum value, simply iterate over the list. You can use the `float('inf')` as a sane initial value for easier comparison.

```
def find_min(self):
    next_node = self.head
    if next_node is None:
        return None

    minimum = float('inf')        
    while next_node:
        value = next_node.getData()
        if value < minimum:
            minimum = value

        next_node = next_node.getNext()

    return minimum
```

As to list clearing, all you need to do is set the `self.head` to `None`. The garbage collector will do the rest.

```
def clear(self):
    self.head = None
    self.count = 0
```